# Fseek to a line number (with lines of variable length)

Tags: c, fseek

I have a large file (~10GB) with variable length lines, and I would like to programmatically go to different line numbers. Is there an efficient way to do so?

Comment: Why exactly do you ask, what is the concrete use case?

Comment: What is this very large file?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain how you got such a large file. Where is it from?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it's a short novel, or maybe Microsoft's NDA:)

Comment: LIke @BasileStarynkevitch says, can you give us more of a clue what is in this, aparrently, massive text file?  Can the lines be sorted?

Answer (score 4):

Yes: build an index.  For example, just once  you can create a text file on the side which contains the byte offset of various line numbers, like this:

```
line,offset
0,0
10000,48272
20000,93726
```

Etc.  Then when you want to go to line 13043, just jump to offset 48272 and skip another 3043 newlines.  Simple and efficient.

Another approach would be to make your line lengths constant.  This would work well if they already have similar lengths so you don't waste too much space.  You can pad them out with `\0` characters or spaces or whatever, then index the file like a big matrix (line N is at N*LEN bytes).

Finally, you could simply write the line numbers at the beginning of the lines themselves.  Then just binary-search within the file, skip to a newline, and inspect the next line number to know whether to look backward or forward (and even guess by how much).

Comment: I would make that an indexed file, using `gdbm` or *sqlite*

Comment: Probably better if the index uses fixed-width format so you can jump to the right entry in the index file to find the position in the text file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: perhaps, then you'd get O(1) in theory...in practice it may not matter because you'd load the index file into memory before using it (probably).  Still, +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no efficient way to do so. You need to scan the entire file once to memorize when are the end of line markers.

Pragmatically, you need a large loop on e.g. [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

You could memoize e.g. the offset of every 100 line, perhaps in a big array or some indexed file using [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) or some [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) database.

My feeling is that you should not have such a huge text file in the first place at all (having a huge text file accessed randomly is the symptom of something wrong). It is not an efficient way to store such data, if you need to access it randomly. You could for example predigest it to fill some database, etc... Probably you should not put such a large piece of data in a text file, but directly in a database or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly with `fseek` since it's only capable of moving the position by a bytes amount.

If the efficiency requirement comes from the fact that you must do it many times back and forth a simple solution could be to scan the whole file once and compute all the lines length, store them in a map or array and then use the values to move exactly where you want.